# VSWindowManager replacement - need to switch VS2010 windows to/from dual monitor config

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, multiple-monitors

I am trying to find a solution that would let me switch between single and multi-monitor configurations in Visual Studio 2010. I see the VSWindowManager has not been updated - is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to look into this after your query...
You can see that development for that hasn't started yet according to the information on code plex for VSWindowManager. (The issue 27831  - has high impact  )

The floating document option is not much appreciated it seems. see
[floating windows](http://blog.meidianto.com/2010/05/18/vs2010-tips-9-moving-from-multiple-documents-window-layout-to-floating-window-of-visual-studio-2010/)

Conclusion: The answer is No. There is no (other) solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can bear a restart of VS, you could setup two vs-shortvuts with a command line parameter to start with different settings-files. One with a single-screen setup and another one with a multi-screen setup.

Works for me like a charm :)

Harry